Updating subgroups in ArcGIS Online
Is there a way to update a group of layers in ArcGIS Online without having to remove the entire group and starting from the beginning?
I have a subgroup of layers that I uploaded to ArcGIS Online at once because they were in the same folder. I need to add another layer to the group. I tried using the Publish Web Layer and the Overwrite Web Layer tools in ArcGIS Pro, and have found that publishing or overwriting with a group of layers is not supported (24035: Layer type is not supported for web feature layer). I am aware of how to create grouped layers in Map Viewer, this question is specifically for hosted feature layers in the ArcGIS Online Content page.
Is there a workaround?

Unless I have not understood, why not simply upload the additional layer, add it to map then move it into the group?

The reason for needing all the layers in a single subgroup of layers is for ease of access when creating maps in ArcGIS Online and when working on the layers in ArcGIS Pro.

The only way I am aware of is to add to the service definition via the REST Admin endpoint of the hosted feature layer. This is a pretty involved process. One example: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-api-for-python-questions/python-api-featurelayercollection-manager-add-to/m-p/770577/highlight/true#M670
